# Query to display all customer purchases

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2022

It is necessary to display all customer purchases (amount, date, name) in
reverse chronological order as long as his credit is greater than zero.
The last line should display the loan balance.

```
DECLARE @Table1 table (Id_Client int, Value money) -- clients
-- Id_Client – client identifier, Value – loan amount

INSERT INTO @Table1 (Id_Client, Value)
SELECT 1, 24
UNION SELECT 2, 13
UNION SELECT 3, 2
UNION SELECT 4, 5

DECLARE @Table2 table (Id_Client int, DocDate datetime, Amount
money, Caption varchar(6)) -- purchases
-- Id_Client – client identifier, Amount – purchase amount,
DocDate – date of purchase, Caption – name of purchase

INSERT INTO @Table2 (Id_Client, Amount, DocDate, Caption)

SELECT 1, 5, '20051024', 'qh'
UNION SELECT 1, 9, '20051019', 'wj'
UNION SELECT 1, 3, '20051022', 'ek'
UNION SELECT 1, 8, '20051004', 'rl'
UNION SELECT 1, 6, '20051018', 'tz'
UNION SELECT 1, 5, '20050929', 'yx'
UNION SELECT 2, 11, '20051023', 'uc'
UNION SELECT 2, 6, '20051021', 'iv'
UNION SELECT 2, 45, '20051018', 'ob'
UNION SELECT 3, 4, '20051030', 'pn'
UNION SELECT 3, 2, '20051028', 'am'
UNION SELECT 4, 4, '20051021', 'sq'
UNION SELECT 4, 6, '20051023', 'dw'
UNION SELECT 4, 8, '20051023', 'fe'
UNION SELECT 4, 9, '20051023', 'gr'
```

The result of the task should be like this

```
1 2005-10-24 00:00:00 5.00   qh
1 2005-10-22 00:00:00 3.00   ek
1 2005-10-19 00:00:00 9.00   wj
1 2005-10-18 00:00:00 6.00   tz
1 2005-10-04 00:00:00 1.00   rl
2 2005-10-23 00:00:00 11.00 uc
2 2005-10-21 00:00:00 2.00   iv
3 2005-10-30 00:00:00 2.00   pn
4 2005-10-23 00:00:00 5.00   gr
```

I was able to write a query that displays all purchases in reverse chronological order, but I still don’t understand how to get the final result

```
WITH AllPurchases AS (
    SELECT
        t2.Id_Client,
        t2.DocDate,
        t2.Amount,
        t2.Caption
    FROM
        Table2 t2
    WHERE
        t2.Id_Client IN (SELECT Id_Client FROM Table1 WHERE Value > 0)
)

SELECT 
    ap.Id_Client,
    ap.DocDate,
    ap.Amount,
    ap.Caption
FROM 
    AllPurchases ap
    INNER JOIN Table1 t1 ON ap.Id_Client = t1.Id_Client
WHERE 
    t1.Value > 0
ORDER BY 
    ap.Id_Client ASC, ap.DocDate DESC
```

I'm using SQL server 2022

The user was given a credit of 24 units.
Explanation of the result. We display the data in chronological order. The result was 5 lines:

```
1) 24 - 5 = 19, remaining credit > 0, output 5
2) 24 - 3 = 16, remaining credit > 0, output 3
3) 16 - 9 = 7, remaining credit > 0, output 9
4) 7 - 6 = 1, remaining credit > 0, output 6
5) Most recent spending in reverse chronological order
1 - 5, < 0, do not output this, but output 1, that is, the remaining balance before the credit is less than 0
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? It looks like SQL Server, but what version?

Comment: Yes I am using SQL server 2022

Comment: It's extremely unclear how your expected output should be derived from the source data - can you perhaps elaborate on that so people can understand? For example, in the results, there is a row for Client 1 dated 2005-10-04 with a caption of 'rl', but the record in Table 2 for that Client, Date and Caption has a different value amount. Your expected output has no column headers to suggest what it is you're trying to calculate and based on the answer I already posted, it's not what's implied by the text of your question, so we need more detail to be able to answer.

Comment: The thing that still unclear after your edits is why you're applying a loan in REVERSE chronological order. It looks like the loan is applied to the most recent purchases first, not the oldest - is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using window functions `lag()` to retrieve previous row and `sum()` to get running total :

**AllPurchases** is used to join data from both tables and calculate the running total.

**cte2** is used to get the previous running total for each client, which will be used in **cte3** to calculate the remaining credit.

**cte3** is responsible for determining the remaining credit based on certain conditions, including the comparison between the current "total" and the previous "running_total" obtained in cte2

```
WITH AllPurchases AS (
    SELECT
        t2.Id_Client,
        t2.DocDate,
        t2.Amount,
        t2.Caption,
        t1.Value as total,
        sum(Amount) over (partition by t2.Id_Client order by DocDate desc ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as running_total
    FROM
        Table2 t2
    INNER JOIN Table1 t1 ON t1.Id_Client = t2.Id_Client
),
cte2 as (
  select *, lag(running_total) over (partition by Id_Client order by DocDate desc) as lag_running_total
  from AllPurchases
),
cte3 as (
  select *, case when total>= running_total then Amount
               when lag_running_total is null then total
               else total - lag_running_total
               end as remaining_credit
  from cte2
)
select Id_Client, DocDate, remaining_credit, Caption
from cte3
where remaining_credit > 0
```

Results :

```
Id_Client   DocDate remaining_credit    Caption
1   2005-10-24 00:00:00.000 5.0000  qh
1   2005-10-22 00:00:00.000 3.0000  ek
1   2005-10-19 00:00:00.000 9.0000  wj
1   2005-10-18 00:00:00.000 6.0000  tz
1   2005-10-04 00:00:00.000 1.0000  rl
2   2005-10-23 00:00:00.000 11.0000 uc
2   2005-10-21 00:00:00.000 2.0000  iv
3   2005-10-30 00:00:00.000 2.0000  pn
4   2005-10-23 00:00:00.000 5.0000  dw
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/JWFuHeFv)

Answer (score -1):

Here's an alternative version:

```sql
SELECT  Id_Client
,   DocDate
,   CASE WHEN aggSum <= Value THEN Amount ELSE Amount + Value - aggSum END AS AmountTop
,   Caption
FROM    (
    SELECT  *
    ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID_Client, CASE WHEN aggSum >= Value THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ORDER BY DocDate DESC, Caption DESC) AS sort
    FROM    (
        SELECT  SUM(Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY t2.ID_Client ORDER BY DocDate DESC, Caption DESC/* ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW*/) AS aggSum, t2.*, t.Value
        FROM    @Table2 t2
        INNER JOIN @Table1 t
            ON  t.Id_Client = t2.Id_Client
        ) x
    ) x
WHERE   aggSum <= Value OR sort = 1
ORDER BY Id_Client, DocDate DESC, Caption DESC
```

It calculates running total and compares it against the available credit.

The `ROW_NUMBER()` partitions rows in two different groups: those where credit is less than aggregated amount spent, and those where it's more.

`CASE WHEN aggSum >= Value THEN 0 ELSE 1 END` so if client exceeds it's credit in the aggregated sum, it creates group 0, otherwise group 1, then the `ORDER BY DocDate DESC` creates a sequence of values 1, 2, 3. This means that the first row where customer exceeds credit gets row number value = 1, second row will get = 2 etc.

And since we're interested in first row where customer credit is overdrawn, we include this row in our calculation in the `WHERE   aggSum <= Value OR sort = 1` part.

It handles rows with same date by using Caption as tiebreaker

Comment: Could you explain your algorithm in more detail? I just don't understand what the sort variable does and what values it takes

Comment: I edited the answer to include a bit longer explanation. Usually it helps to output the values of these temporary columns so you can understand what happens